Able to push commits to another GitHub account's repo
I have been using git for my main GitHub account for a while. I have this set by doing the git config --global user.name and git config --global user.email commands. I recently got a job where I was to make a new GitHub account, and after creating this new account I did the following commands listed above to set my git to this new account.
I just discovered that I'm allowed to push to my old accounts repos from this new account, how is this? I thought that write access to a repo is restricted to only the repo's creator by default. Basically, my old account (account A) has a repo that this new account (account B) is able to push new commits to with no problem.

The user used for pushing is unrelated to the username/email used for committing. You can commit with one user and push with another.

there is a common confusion: user.name and user.email are used by git to name the author or committer of commits you create on your machine. The credentials you use to connect to a remote server, on the other hand, are described in the url of the remote repo -- and possibly an ssh key or a password stored in a manager.

Ok thank you for responses, so by default is any user allowed to push code to any public repo? My repo had no protections on main branch, does that mean anybody can push code?

No. By default, only collaborators/the owner/certain organization members can push to repositories. However, this can be different from the user specified with user.name/user.email

Does this answer your question? Git commit user is different than git push user

Yes thank you, it has cleared up a lot for me.

It has nothing to do with your configured email/username.  It has more to do with your specific permissions on the repository, the account you're using, and the private/public key configuration in the settings.
It sounds like you're using the same Github account as before and not a new account, right?  The new company simply invited your current user to their repo and now you have visibility, right?  Unless you're using a totally new account with a different private/public key pair, it kind of does not affect your current repositories.
